# SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(database_closed))

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

The two pages in the application are listed with database(sqlite). but when I want to switch between pages, I get such an error: SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(database_closed))

please help mee.. I don't understand why see this error.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:bankingapp/models/coin.dart';
import 'package:bankingapp/models/histories.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DbHelper {
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    return _db ??= await initDb();
  }

  Future<Database> initDb() async {
    var dbFolder = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(dbFolder, 'app.db');

    // Delete any existing database:
    await deleteDatabase(path);

    // Create the writable database file from the bundled demo database file:
    try {
      await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
    } catch (_) {}
    ByteData data =
        await rootBundle.load(join("assets/database", "bankingapp.db"));
    List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);

    //open the database
    return await openDatabase(path);

    /*
    var dbFolder = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(dbFolder, 'app.db');
    
    return await openDatabase(path);*/
  }

  Future<List<Histories>> getHistories() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Histories");
    return result.map((data) => Histories.fromMap(data)).toList();
  }

  Future<List<Coins>> getCoins() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Coins");
    return result.map((data) => Coins.fromMap(data)).toList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, **uninstall** the app from the device and run `flutter clean` and then build a new app and run it again to see if the error occurs.

Then, check the device in which you are running your app has restricted your app or not, see if your device requires any particular permission.

If it still occurs according to your provided information it seems like the problem is either the database is **getting closed** or it's **not opening** it can be because of many reasons like not doing proper initialization or even just forgetting to put `await`. Check the **database initialization code** in which you are opening your database or not then check if you are by mistake **closing the database** somewhere, which should have been done only when the app is terminated.

If you have done both of the above steps correct check your **database location** and **mapping**.

If nothing is working please try to follow official [sqflite docs and example](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), as your code seems different from the one shown in the plugin example.

Comment: Hope it helps, if yes then please upvote and mark it correct so that it will be easier for others searching for the same error to find answer

Comment: i checked everything you said it.
i don't use "close db" function anywhere...

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your updated question. please check it out if still, any problem feel free to ask in the comments.